# Joomla 3 mysql error SQL Error = 0?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.2

im using joomla3 for my new site , i used 3.2.2 and currently update to 3.2.3. but its always giving me mysql errors form several tables when browsing ste also saving values from backe end

> Error displaying the error page: SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `sltdb_template_styles`: SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `sltdb_template_styles`

How to overcome this .. please advice ?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Lodder : mysql 5.5  php 5.3.13

Answer (score 0):

It looks like database connectivity
 Try to access the database from the application server using the command line. or try to access your database via PHPAdmin

**If still no chance:**
Here is fix - i got for google
Use Extension manager->Discover and Install, possibly followed by an Extension manager->Database and Fix when needed.

Joomla requires a proper working infrastructure. Something must have failed otherwise the update should have succeeded. The above steps are normal procedure for fixing when something went wrong. An alterative would be to restore and try again.

Also, Joomla allows you to break down the steps. Using the Extension manager install from directory is the least resourceful way to update. It requires you to download, extract and copy it to the webserver yourself.

Comment: so you ask me to check the specific table from phpmyadmin isnt it ? im getting this error with some other table names as  well

Comment: I doubts its a database connection problem as I believe it happened after the update. Joomla updates dont mess with the configiration.php file. Also, the OP is still able to access the backend

Comment: @ Lodder : backend can access , but when saving data (Ex: adding categories ) its prompt this error, then i have to refresh the browser . same happen on frontend as well. I did database fix as well

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help someone. I had this issue after a server move and it turned out that it was due to a module (wp_posts) that had old db credentials in it, i corrected the credentials which fixed the issue.

Unrelated but one other thing to check if you have this type of issue is can you update things in admin, I had a secondary issues with was that APC cache was not enabled on the new webserver, i discovered that by trying to update things in admin and viewing errors.

The error 0 message is very unhelpful, it seems this could be module specific though rather than joomla itself but it seems quite poor that a module can block the entire site form working, some error trapping needed me thinks!

Answer (score 0):

Cannot comment, yet ... (as a comment to logicc's answer)

Well, the "Error: 0" is indeed not very helpful, but with debugging turned on, you at least get a good idea of where the problem might be coming from:

```
24 JDatabaseDriver->loadObjectList() /.../modules/mod_wpposts/helper.php:91
25 JDatabaseDriverMysql->connect() /.../libraries/joomla/database/driver.php:1312
```

About the module blocking the entire page - that might make sense in some cases (a module so important that you would rather have the page not render, at all, than in part?), but it certainly seems like a bad default. For now, I think modules should take care of that themselves with some try-catch-ing.

Comment: I know not being able to comment is a little frustrating at times, but using an answer as a way around this is not how the site should be used. For more information, please see: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174)

Comment: That is frustrating, indeed - especially for infrequent users ... Thanks for the pointers. So, if possible, anyone feel free to move this comment.